# Python Date Ranges with Offsets for Actual Begin/End of 7-Day Weeks

Tags: python, pandas

I need to generate the start/end of weekly date ranges given a year as a simple range that goes df['start'] and df['end'].

I have the following solution, but it is not fully inclusive and maybe a bit hacky. And it needs to be general so that it's not dependent on the year (2018, 2019, etc.). I am curious if there is something more accurate.

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
# create weekly range
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range("20180101", "20181231",freq='7d'), columns=['start_date'])

# add end date from weekly-range start date
df['end_date'] = df['start_date'].shift(-1)

# manually adjust to create a "true" week range
df['end_date'] = df['end_date'] - pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='d')
```

`df.head()`

[image]

`df.tail()`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not necessary last missing value I think simpliest is add 6 days:

```
df['end_date'] = df['start_date'] + pd.to_timedelta(6, unit='d')
```

If need last missing value:

```
df['end_date'] = df['start_date'].iloc[:-1] + pd.to_timedelta(6, unit='d')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use timedelta and days as argument which is 6 in your case.

```
from datetime import timedelta
df['end_date'] = df['start_date'] + timedelta(days=6)
```